# I want to update a table to number the positions of orders

Tags: sql, count, firebird

I have a legacy table with orders and their (sometimes multiple) rows with varchar values:

```
Order       Row
1           1
1           1a
1           1b
2           1
2           2
```

I want to introduce another integer field "ROW_NR"

```
Order       Row      ROW_NR
1           1         1
1           1a        2
1           1b        3
2           1         1
2           2         2
```

which will hold the number of the row in the resp. order.

How can I accomplish updating the new field using SQL?

Comment: Which Firebird version are you using, how is the order of increments decided, and what did you try to do to achieve this?

Comment: This is a client side task, not server side.

Answer (score 0):

Window-Functions can be used to achieve this, like described in [Firebird windowing](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/community/ppts/fbcon11/fb3windowing.pdf)

(Using keywords as column-name is a bad practice, in example replaced by *order* and *row*.)

```
ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY _order_ order by _row_ asc) as row_num
```